# Variable name changes and missing data

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am querying data through the Core Reporting API and using the query tool to test the queries. I attempted to pull the dimensions ga:userGender and ga:userAgeBracket; however, there are zero results prior to 2014-06-10. I noticed that later in June, 2014 the names of these variables changed. Is this a coincidence or does this result imply something different?

Thank you,

Comment: It is just a coincidence. They only add or rename variable but they do not remove them.

Comment: Those dimensions are only available if the "demographics" features are enabled in the property settings, so you might want to check your account history if those were active in the selected timeframe (maybe demographics was only enabled on 2014-06-10).

Comment: Thank you, dikesh, for the confirmation. Thank you, Eike, for the suggestion.